# Loading csv data and save results to a variable

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to load data from a csv file and store the data in a dictionary variable named store as key routes. The first lines of the csv file look like this:

```
ID,AirlineID,AirlineName,AirlineCountry,SourceAirportID,SourceAirportCode,SourceAirport,SourceCity,SourceCountry,SourceLatitude,SourceLongitude,DestAirportID,DestCode,DestAirport,DestCity,DestCountry,DestLatitude,DestLongitude
1,24,American Airlines,United States,4355,ABE,Lehigh Valley International Airport,Allentown,United States,40.65209961,-75.44080353,3876,CLT,Charlotte Douglas International Airport,Charlotte,United States,35.2140007,-80.94309998
2,24,American Airlines,United States,4355,ABE,Lehigh Valley International Airport,Allentown,United States,40.65209961,-75.44080353,3752,PHL,Philadelphia International Airport,Philadelphia,United States,39.87189865,-75.2410965
3,24,American Airlines,United States,3718,ABI,Abilene Regional Airport,Abilene,United States,32.41130066,-99.68190002,3670,DFW,Dallas Fort Worth International Airport,Dallas-Fort Worth,United States,32.896801,-97.03800201
```

Here is how I am trying load the data and store the results onto store.routes. I only get an empty "{}" dictionary in the console.

```
let store = {};

function loadData() {

    let promise = d3.csv("routes.csv")

    return promise.then(routes => {
    store.routes = routes;
        return store;
    })
}
loadData();
console.log(store.routes);
```

Comment: It should be as simple as "store.routes = routes". I'd make sure that 1) the loadData function is called. 2) You are checking the value after the promise completes 3) The ".then" portion of code is getting actual data. A codepen or similar always assists in debugging

Comment: Thank you for your feedback cmonkey. But, when I routes to store.routes, call the loadData function and then do a console of store.routes the console still does not display any data. It just shows the word store and an empty { }.

Answer (score 2):

What might be confusing here, is that the data loading is asynchronous, meaning that you have to wait until the promise is resolved before you can use the data.

You have a couple of options of going about this - a [callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), or [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). I've wrote a short script exemplifying their usage:

```
const store = {};

const doViz = (routes, dataRetrievalOrigin) => {
  console.log(routes, dataRetrievalOrigin)
  store.routes = routes
}

const loadDataWithCallback = (callback) => {
  d3.csv("../data/routes.csv")
    .then((routes) => {
      callback(routes)
    })
}

loadDataWithCallback((routes) => {
  doViz(routes, 'Data loaded from loadDataWithCallback')
})

const loadDataWithPromise = () => {
  return d3.csv("../data/routes.csv")
}

loadDataWithPromise().then((routes) => {
  doViz(routes, 'Data loaded from loadDataWithPromise')
})

const loadDataWithAsync = async () => {
  return d3.csv("../data/routes.csv")
}

;(async () => {
  doViz(await loadDataWithAsync(), 'Data loaded from loadDataWithAsync')
})()
```

The common trait among the three examples are that they

1. Initiate a data retrieval request via `d3.csv`
2. Waits until the data retrieval is complete
3. Calls the `doViz` function with the retrieved data

Given that `d3.csv` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), I'm guessing that the structure of `loadDataWithPromise` might the most straightforward one to use.

--- Edit ---

Here is how to do it, closely mimicking your current approach. Notice that `console.log(store.routes)` is put into a function, that is called when the Promise resolves. This makes sure it is executed after the asynchronous data retrieval is complete.

```
const store = {};

const logData = () => {
  console.log(store.routes)
}

const loadData = () => {
  return d3.csv('../data/routes.csv')
    .then((routes) => {
      store.routes = routes
      logData()
    })
}

loadData()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. I updated the code to show to reflect what I've recently tried. I'm not sure how to leverage the good info you provided due to my inexperience.

Comment: Asynchronous functions can be quite confusing. Your data retrieval in `loadData` is asynchronous, which means that it will return at some point whenever it's finished. Your code does not wait for the data retrieval to complete, meaning it `console.log` your `store` before it is populated with `routes`. To wait for the data retrieval to complete, you should put your `console.log` into a function, which you call after setting `store.routes = routes`. I've added an example that closely mimicks your current approach.