# D3.csv not returning data getting Promise Pending

Tags: d3.js

I don't get any data back from D3.js promise. The following code works if I crate a variable with a list of objects and use that for my data. But, when I try to create a variable of the same name using d3.csv I don't anything back in the console. I just get "Promise {}. Please help. Thank you.

```
<script>
            var h = 350;
            var w = 500;

        var monthlySales;

        var loadData = () => { 
            return d3.csv("data/MonthlySales.csv")
                    .then( (d) => { monthlySales = d } ) };

        loadData();
        console.log(monthlySales);

            // var monthlySales = [
            //     {"month":10, "sales":100},
            //     {"month":20, "sales":130},
            //     {"month":30, "sales":250},
            //     {"month":40, "sales":300},
            //     {"month":50, "sales":265},
            //     {"month":60, "sales":225},
            //     {"month":70, "sales":180},
            //     {"month":80, "sales":120},
            //     {"month":90, "sales":145},
            //     {"month":100, "sales":130},
            // ];

            var lineFun = d3.line()
                .x((d) => d.month*3)
                .y((d) => h - d.sales)
                .curve(d3.curveLinear);

            var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

            var viz = svg.append("path")
                .attr("d", lineFun(monthlySales))
                .attr("stroke", "purple")
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("fill", "none");

            var labels = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(monthlySales)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .text((d) => d.sales)
                .attr("x", (d) => d.month*3-25)
                .attr("y", (d) => h - d.sales)
                .style("font-size", "12px")
                .style("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .attr("fill", "#666666")
                .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("font-weight", function(d,i) { 
                    if (i === 0 || i ==(monthlySales.length-1) ) {
                        return "bold";
                    } else { return "normal"; }
                });
        </script>
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the answer I posted last time you asked about promises? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57205820/3252752

Comment: It required more coding intellect than I currently have and I could not get it to work for me. I'm trying to get better everyday. I tried the code in the reference you provided and I am updating the above post with that code. I still get errors. I guess I need a simpler approach that I won't mess up. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: I've posted a new answer that tells you what to do as well as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Building on my answer to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57205820/3252752, you can go about this is two ways:

Both of them requires that you put all of your code after `loadData();` into a structure that is executed after the Promise resolves.

The easiest way, change the loadData function to this:

```
var loadData = () => { 
    return d3.csv("data/MonthlySales.csv")
            .then( (d) => { 
                monthlySales = d;
                /* Put all code after 'loadData();' here */
            } 
        )};

loadData();        
/* Take all remaining code from after here */
```

The nicer way, puts the code into a separate function:

```
var doViz = () => {
    /* Put all code after 'loadData();' here */
}

var loadData = () => { 
    return d3.csv("data/MonthlySales.csv")
            .then( (d) => { 
                monthlySales = d;
                doViz();
            } 
        )};

loadData();
/* Take all remaining code from after here */
```